# Undefined method `user' - Extending the Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm working on a Todo List application, everything I’ve done is from chapter 10 onwards, and i've been using the parts of chapter 11 that I need to get this far. I've already done what I’m trying to do on other sections of the site with buttons only viewable to the user that made the todo list, and the correct users todo's are on the profile page, but for some reason I can't seem to get the same thing working with the static pages controllers home action. Basically, it's 99% finished apart from the correct users todo lists displaying on the home page,  depending on if you're logged in, if you're not logged in you see something else.

The whole **home.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user?(@todo_list.user) %>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="well">
            <p class="todo_list_title"><%= link_to todo_list.title,   todo_list %></p>
            <p class="todo_list_description"><%= todo_list.description %>
            | <%= link_to "Show", todo_list_path(todo_list) %> 
            | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_todo_list_path(todo_list) %> 
            | <%= link_to 'Delete', todo_list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <% end %>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <%= link_to "New Todo List", new_todo_list_path, 
                   class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<% else %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
    <h1>Todo List App</h1>

    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg   btn-primary"  %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**static_pages_controller.rb**

With the static_pages_controller home action like this

```
def home
    @todo_lists = TodoList.all
end
```

The following are combinations of home.html.erb with the result it gives

```
<% if logged_in? %>
```

this shows  all users todo lists

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user?(@todo_list) %>
```

this catches the else statement

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user?(@todo_list.user) %>
```

undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

With the **static_pages_controller** like this

```
def home
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@todo_lists = TodoList.all
end
```

or like this ...

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :correct_user

def home
    @user = User.find(correct_user)
    @todo_lists = @user.todo_lists.paginate(page: params[:page])
end


private

    def logged_in_user
        unless logged_in?
            store_location
            flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
            redirect_to login_url
        end
    end

    def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

All three of the above example give this error

**Couldn't find User with 'id'=**

It seems like any combination of logged_in_user, and correct_user methods under private dont't work, I always seem to end up with one of the above errors, which is a bit frustrating when i've got the users profile working when the correct user is logged in.

I'm sure the answer is dead simple, as it always seems to be, but I can't see it

Regards
Shaun

**UPDATE**

```
# Returns true if the given user is the current user.
def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end

# Define the method current_user
def current_user
    # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).

    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: this variable `@todo_list` is nil and you are trying to do `@todo_list.user` which is causing this error `undefined method user for nil:NilClass` and why `@todo_list` is nil bcoz in home action. you are not setting anything in `@todo_list`

Comment: Isn't that what this line is doing.?.. @todo_lists = @user.todo_lists.paginate(page: params[:page])

Comment: so this line `@todo_lists = @user.todo_lists.paginate(page: params[:page])` set the user's todo_lists in `@todo_lists` object which is array. and this line `<% if logged_in? && current_user?(@todo_list.user) %>`  trying to fetch user from `@todo_list` you see `s` is missing. secondly you can not find user from array of @todo_lists

Comment: So how would i find the user ? Thats the bit i can't figure out mate

Comment: what is the difference between @user and current user. and secondly can you share the code for this `current_user?` method.?

Comment: I've just updated the main post with the two methods mate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84902/discussion-between-athar-and-shaun).

Comment: Try changing `@user = User.find(params[:id])` to `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` in `correct_user` method.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need the full error message (along with the first few lines of the stack trace / file & line identifiers) in order to give you a more precise answer. But based on what you've shared, I'm guessing one of two things are true:

1. Your `@todo_list` object is `nil` or wasn't defined properly. Check in the controller; I see you defined `@todo_lists` (note the plural) but if you didn't define `@todo_list` then it will default to `nil`, and of course `nil` doesn't know the method `.user` so you'll get an error.
2. If you're sure (and can prove) that `@todo_list` is indeed defined and is a TodoList object as expected, it's possible that TodoList objects don't know the `.user` method. You can verify this by going into the Rails console, creating a new TodoList object, and trying to call `.user` on it; if you get an error there, you'll definitely get an error in the above view templates. In ActiveRecord, you'd likely fix this by telling TodoList.rb that it `belongs_to :user` - this should add the necessary method.

Incidentally, I'm skeptical about how you're using that `current_user?` method. It looks like the first time you call it, you pass in the `@todo_list` object... even if it's defined properly, how can you expect a TodoList object to be the current user? Why are you even calling that method with that object?

Comment: I just noticed a downvote, care to comment on the reason or what I could have said / done to be more helpful? thanks!